# How to decrypt a password des(unix) with 13 string with python

Tags: python, unix, cryptography, des

Here my decode a password with 13 string

U5IhmemtXSSA. ===> admin

G1Cbobnlhh9xA ===> flower

What function or code should I use to decode a password like that?

Comment: Python is the wrong tool for the job (google hashcat...), and your question is probably off-topic as well. Basically you have to brute force it.

Comment: what type of this encrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your title says it's a Unix style [`crypt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) (salted) password hash.  to verify under Python you can do:

```
from crypt import crypt
print(crypt('admin', 'U5'))
```

and you'll get `U5IhmemtXSSA.` back.

cryptographic hashes can't be "decrypted" in the traditional sense, but you can enumerate possible inputs to find out which ones result in the same hash.  as suggested by @schlenk you could try [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) or you could try something like [john the ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) to quickly do this.